# Python Image Library: image saved after pixel manipulation is always white

Tags: python, image

I have the following code. src_img is a 1250x1250 rgb image. I want to create another grayscale image with averaged intensity.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(src_img)
width, height = img.size
avg_img = Image.new('1', img.size, 'black')

avg_pixels = avg_img.load()

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r, g, b = img.getpixel((x, y))
        avg_pixels[x, y] = int((r + g + b) / 3.0)

avg_img.save('avg.tiff')
```

But the resulting avg.tiff file is plain white. I can see that avg_pixels has the necessary values but the saved image doesn't correspond to those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mode '1' is a bilevel image - meaning either white or black. For grayscale, you want 'L'.

```
avg_img = Image.new('L', img.size, 'black')
```